# How do I reverse a string (not in place) in C?

Tags: c, string

I've searched, but all I can find is where a function to reverse a string in place. Here's what I have so far:

```
char* reverseString(char* string)
{
    int i, j;
    char reversed[sizeof(string)];
    j = strlen(string);

    for (i = strlen(string); i >= 0; i--)
    {
        reversed[j - i] = string[i];
    }
    return reversed;
}
```

However, that hits the issue of reversed being a local variable, so returning a pointer to it throws

```
warning: function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
```

Comment: Get pointer to `reversed` as an argument and define it out of this function.

Comment: @saeedn Is there any other way to do it? I'd much prefer creating the variable inside the function and returning it/it's value

Comment: In addition to the warning there are more problems with your code. 1. The allocated buffer is not the right size. You need to allocate `strlen(string)+1` bytes.  2. The array indexes in the copy loop are off by one and will put the nul-terminator first in the reversed string.  3. You fail to put a nul-terminator at the end of the reversed string.

Comment: You may allocate `reversed` on heap (using `malloc`) and return its pointer if you want to create it in function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically allocate memory for it:

```
char* reverseString(char* string)
{
    int i;
    int j = strlen(string);
    char *reversed = malloc(j + 1);
    ...
```

In this case, the caller must remember to free() the allocated buffer that is returned.

Or you can have caller to pass in a buffer that's large enough to hold the reversed string:

```
char* reverseString(char* string, char *reversed)
{
     int i, j;
     j = strlen(string);

     for (i = strlen(string); i >= 0; i--)
     {
 ...
```

Note also that in your current code: `char reversed[sizeof(string)];` is wrong,
inside this function `string` is just a `char*` , so `sizeof(string)` gives you the size of a `char*`, not the length of the string this char* points to.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the expression `sizeof(string)` returns the size of the *pointer*, not the length of the string. Use `strlen(string)` for that too. And as noted by ta.speot.is you need to add one character for the terminating `'\0'`, as well as add that terminator to the reversed string.

As for your problem, the variable `reversed` is stored on the stack, and when the function returns that area of the memory is not available to you anymore. You either have to allocate that memory on the heap with e.g. `malloc` (and free that memory later with `free`) or to make the variable `static` but in that case you can't use it in a multi-threaded program.

Comment: Ah I see. So how would I make the memory permanent instead of disappearing once the function returns?

Comment: @ChintanParikh either declare it on heap, or use static memory or pass the pointer as argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can either allocate space for the reversed string with malloc or let the caller provide space for the new string.
The latter usually reduces the risk of programming errors causing memory leaks.

```
void reverseString(char *reversed, char *string)
{
    int i, j;
    j = strlen(string);

    for (i = strlen(string) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        reversed[i] = string[j-i];
    }
    reversed[j] = 0;  /* Don't forget to nul-terminate the reversed string */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide the target buffer if you do not want to allocate in your function and then return that. The responsibility then is by the caller that reversed is big enough to fit source.

```
char* reverseString(char* source, char* reversed) {...}
```

and yes sizeof is not the correct way to check a string size, use strlen()